# Get Specific Cell's Data (php and mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem on getting the data from a single cell. Here's how it should work;
 I have a database named: users and a table name: users. Yea it's the same. I have columns which are id, username, password, email, coins.
What I want to do is whenever someone logs in, for example: 'Gregor' account, his coins will be shown on the page. So I'm wondering how I can show the current user's coin count. Thanks.

Comment: In this forum you should first try something and came again if your code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @user10089632 This site is definitely **not** a forum.

Comment: @FeiXiang, I agree. I suspected he is used to forums, so I tried to match his thinking

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty basic sql query... all you have to do is something like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli('your_mysql_url', 'your_mysql_user', 'your_mysql_password', 'users');
$stm =  $conn->query("select * from users where username = 'Gregor'");
$userData = $stm->fetch_assoc();
$coins = $userData['coins'];
```